# this.camera.getPicture(options) not working | Ionic

Tags: node.js, typescript, ionic-framework

I am developing an Ionic app and I want to create a camera option. I've been looking for information and examples so I am using the plugin @ionic-native/camera. Nevertheless, the button to take a picture does not work. When I click the Take Picture's button I get the alert that is inside the error handler.
What's wrong?

Here's my code:

camera.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-camera',
  templateUrl: 'camera.html',
})

export class CameraPage {

  public photos : any;
  public base64Image : string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private camera: Camera, private alertCtrl : AlertController) {}

 ngOnInit() {
   this.photos = [];
 }

 deletePhoto(index) {
   let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
   title: 'Sure you want to delete this photo? There is NO undo!',
   message: '',
   buttons: [
    {
      text: 'No',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Disagree clicked');
      }
    }, {
      text: 'Yes',
      handler: () => {
        console.log('Agree clicked');
        this.photos.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  ]
  });
  confirm.present();
}

takePhoto(){
  const options : CameraOptions = {
    quality: 50, 
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
 }
 this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
   this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
   this.photos.push(this.base64Image);
   this.photos.reverse();
 }, (err) => {
   alert("Error");
   console.log(err);
 });
 }


}
```

camera.html:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Camera</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content padding class="card-background-page">

<button ion-button full (click)="takePhoto()">
    <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon> &nbsp;&nbsp; Take Photo
</button>

<ion-col col-6 *ngFor="let photo of photos; let id = index">
    <ion-card class="block">
        <ion-icon name="trash" class="deleteIcon" (click)="deletePhoto(id)">
</ion-icon>
        <img [src]="photo" *ngIf="photo" />
    </ion-card>
</ion-col>
```

Comment: Try running the project on a device attached to Xcode or Android Studio so you can see the log, might give you some more detail as to what is failing, perhaps the plugin isn't installed properly? What are you running it on?

Comment: I am running it in my smartphone (Android). I'll be trying debugging with AndroidStudio but I don't know what can be the issue.

Comment: There should be an exception in the logs in Android Studio when you run the app via it and attempt to click the 'Take Picture's button', let me know what you see there and I may be able to help.